# Jupyter Notebook ModuleNotFound error for a module that is installed

Tags: python, jupyter

I have a conda virtual environment, called pymatgenWork, with anaconda 3.6.1 python installed.  I have installed a package named pymatgen using a conda install.  It works from the shell.

I activate my pymatgenWork environment and start the jupyter notebook server.

I open a new notebook and do:

> /!conda list

which shows clearly that the pymatgenWork environment is active and that the pymatgen package is installed.

I then try:

> import pymatgen as mg

and get the error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymatgen'

I have stared at this for a long time and thing the problem is that I need to specify the path to this pymatgen model, but I'm not sure how to do it.  I have the path in my .bash_profile which solves the problem when working in the shell, but would love advice/direction on how to solve it within a notebook.  Or if I am missing something else, I'd appreciate knowing what's up.

Thanks in advance.

-David

Comment: (I know this is basic) but have you tried uninstalling it and then reinstalling it?

Comment: Also, why is your username Sophie when you signed David?

Comment: Thanks Liam.  I have not tried uninstalling and reinstalling, yet.  I am still hoping it is a simple Path problem that can be resolved easily.

As for the username... I don't really have an answer.  My profile seems to have usurped the name of my long deceased Grandmother.  Most odd.  I will go to my profile and fix it, but if my Grandmother is haunting Stack Overflow, she may change it back...

Comment: Tried uninstalling and reinstalling.  No joy.  

Odd to me that this package, pymatgen, sits in the same directory as matplotlib and I can import matplotlib without problem.  That suggests that the issue is not path related. 

I've tried stopping the kernel server and restarting everything.

Comment: Can you add the output of: import sys
sys.path