# ModuleNotFoundError in Jupyter Lab for package pycwt

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter-lab

I have a conda environment where I have installed the wavelet package [pycwt](https://pypi.org/project/pycwt/) using:

```
conda install -n myenv -c conda-forge pycwt
```

as prescribed in the [Anaconda cloud](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pycwt).

On my terminal, the command `import pycwt` works just fine. When I open a **notebook** on Jupyter Lab (within the virtual environment), running

```py
import pycwt
```

yields

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-501c582ee37d> in <module>
----> 1 import pycwt

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycwt'
```

The same command works fine when I run it on a terminal **within Jupyter Lab**. Other packages I have installed in the virtual environment run just fine in both the notebook and on the terminal.

It looks like there are similar questions on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51433227/jupyter-lab-installing-importing-packages) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45513938/jupyter-notebook-modulenotfound-error-for-a-module-that-is-installed) but neither have been answered yet.

Comment: did you restart your computer?

Comment: Just tried, did not fix it :(

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out: It looks like my notebook in Jupyter Lab was running the base kernel and not the kernel of the virtual environment. I typed

```py
import sys
sys.executable
```

into my notebook and got the result

```
'/anaconda3/bin/python'
```

instead of the desired

```
'/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin/python'
```

I solved it by following the instructions in the [iPython documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-different-environments). In summary, I needed to install a new iPython kernel for my new environment. Run:

```sh
conda install -n myenv ipython
conda activate myenv
python -m ipykernel install --user --name myenv --display-name "Python (myenv)"
```

Then, to run Jupyter Lab in the new environment:

```
conda activate myenv
jupyter lab
```

And I was able to select the kernel "Python (myenv)" when I opened a new notebook (also in the top right of an existing notebook).

Comment: This may work, but it's definitely not how it should be.