# Importing library error: No module named <pkg>

Tags: python, git, github, pip

In the past, I downloaded an open-source package through pip when I was just using it and it worked fine but I have recently started to help with the development of the package so I cloned the github repository onto my laptop and am now having troubles. I checked out and pulled the changes to a new branch in the github repository to work with some changes someone else made but my Jupyter Notebook was still using the old version of the package as I couldn't access the new methods in the notebook I was working in. If I open the code through 'open .' when in the directory, I can see that it is the proper code that I need to run but Jupyter notebook was not running that code. I then ran 'pip freeze' in my terminal and saw a package was still installed there so I ran 'sudo pip uninstall ' and uninstalled the package from pip. Although now, when I try to import the package into my Jupyter Notebook I get the error where there is:

```
No module named <package name>
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it? I would like to be able to use the version of the code of which branch I am in currently.

EDIT:

The package library is stored in /Users/myName/pkg. I am trying to access this through the 'import ' statement in Python. I am running this import statement through a Jupyter notebook in Jupyter lab. Jupyter lab is installed under python3.7/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-lab. I used to have another version of this open-source library installed which I installed using pip, but I recently uninstalled it as I thought that was causing the problem.

I also ran

```
sys.executable
```

and it returned '/anaconda3/bin/python'

EDIT 2:

I tried following the solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56866495/modulenotfounderror-in-jupyter-lab-for-package-pycwt) but when I activated my new environment created, my entire jupyter lab local-host page just kept refreshing constantly and would not load anything. Although when I do not activate that environment I can run my old jupyter lab fine.

EDIT 3:

**SOLUTION:**
The solution I linked above worked for me, although I also had to update my Jupyter Lab in the new conda environment to stop my page from being [infinitely refreshed](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/8123).

Comment: It would help if you share what project you're talking about, how things are structured in your project folder (i.e. where the package is, where the source file importing it is and what your import statement looks like)

Comment: @Grismar just updated with more information now

Comment: In Jupyter, or from your script, you can list where Python looks for packages and modules with `sys.path` - likely, `/Users/myName/` isn't part of that and you should add it if you need source files to be in the places they are right now. Alternatively, you would build and install the package in the environment your notebook runs in, but it sounds like you want access to the package while you're editing it.

Comment: @Grismar When I run that command I get  '/Users/myName/'  in my first line of the return. I saw [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56866495/modulenotfounderror-in-jupyter-lab-for-package-pycwt) and am thinking I may have to install a new iPython kernel

Comment: @Grismar Just found a solution and posted it in an edit, thanks for the help!